# Is there any PhpStorm plugin to allow editing of INI files in a tabular form?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

[PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (as of v2016.3.2) already allows editing the CSV format text files in a tabular view. I usually work with lot of INI files with syntax similar to

```
key_name_a="Value for Key A"
key_name_b="Value for Key B"
```

I tried looking for some plugin to achieve this but could not find one.

I found [Ini4Idea
for IntelliJ IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/6981-ini4idea)
and [Editing CSV and Similar Files in Table Format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/editing-csv-and-similar-files-in-table-format.html), but these do not solve my purpose.

Comment: Have not seen such plugin. And I have no idea what to suggest here .. as `.ini` has different format to CSV/TSV. The best I can offer -- MS Excel or alike (LibreOffice etc) -- at very least MS Excel can open such file if you specify what delimiters to use etc. Obviously - it will not handle any comments that `.ini` file may have ... and I'm not sure how it will handle multi-line entries; not sure how you can tell it that `key` part should not have quotes around it but `value` part should have it.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the CSV functionality of PhpStorm to edit INI files in tabular form, with little preparations. No additional plugin is required; the functionality is provided by the "Database Tools" plugin that is bundled with PhpStorm and enabled by default.

Open an INI file then run the command "Edit as Table..." from the "Edit" menu. It opens a dialog box where you can choose the "Value separator" (it defaults to `Tab`, you remove it and enter `=` instead) and check the option "First column is header". On the right side of the dialog box you can preview how PhpStorm renders your file as a table using the configuration you changed.

PhpStorm remembers the settings for the file (even across restarts) but unfortunately it seems there is no way to save a new set of parameters (other than modifying the two existing configurations) in order to apply it to a different file.